# Oracle INVALID_NUMBER exception in my function does not work

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql

The Oracle function below assign 'A' to number variable.
But the Exception clause does not catch `INVALID_NUMBER` system exception.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST2
    (P1 IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER AS V_VALUE NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT(
        --SELECT 1/TO_NUMBER(P1)
        SELECT 'A'
        FROM DUAL
        )
    INTO V_VALUE
    FROM DUAL;
    RETURN V_VALUE;

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN INVALID_NUMBER THEN  -- If I change INVALID_NUMBER to OTHERS, then it works.
      RETURN -1;      
END;
/


SELECT TEST2('1') FROM DUAL;
```

When I change `INVALID_NUMBER` to `OTHERS`, then it works.

How to modify above code to chatch the `INVALID_NUMBER` exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some more info (to what Barbaros already told you).

> The INVALID_NUMBER Exception (ORA-01722) occurs in a SQL statement when the conversion of a character string into a number fails because the string does not represent a valid number. **(In procedural statements, VALUE_ERROR is raised.)** This exception is also raised when the LIMIT-clause expression in a bulk FETCH statement does not evaluate to a positive number.

Compare

```
SQL> select 'a'/2 from dual;
select 'a'/2 from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

to

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_num number;
  3  begin
  4    l_num := 'a' / 2;
  5  end;
  6  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

to

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_num number;
  3  begin
  4    select 'a' / 2 into l_num from dual;
  5  end;
  6  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

Isn't that nice of Oracle? More or less the same thing, but different response.

Answer (score 4):

Because you get `VALUE_ERROR` when `ORA-06502` raised as occurs in your case. So, replace `INVALID_NUMBER` with `VALUE_ERROR`.

as an example; if the `SELECT` statement was :

```
SELECT 5
  INTO V_VALUE
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE TO_NUMBER('A')=1;
```

you'd get `INVALID_NUMBER`(`ORA-01722`) exception.